# How many objects are created per request in this GAE app?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, wsgi

I'm developing a Google App Engine application with Python and Webapp2.  For this question, the relevant parts are:

```
import webapp2

my_object = MyClass()

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    # do stuff

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage)
], debug=True)
```

So, every time my app is accesed, `MainPage` request handler takes care of the request. Let's assume there are 100 users using the app at a given moment. My questions are:

- How many `webapp2.WSGIApplication` instances are created? Just 1? 100? (If I understood WSGI, I think that just 1)
- How many `MyClass` instances are created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Google App Engine, count on 100 instances of both `MainPage()` and `MyClass` being created; each user visiting your site potentially is routed to a different machine in the vast Google cloud.

Run locally, `MyClass` will be instantiated once *per process*; some WSGI servers run multiple procsses (forking) to handle incoming requests. A `MainPage` itstance is created for each incoming request (so 100 times).

Comment: Mmm... but is the relation MainPage - webapp2.WSGIApplication a 1:1 relation?

Comment: @jorgeas80: The *class* is passed in, and the webapp2 will create instances of that class as needed to handle requests.